Django Ñ problem? ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
I'm working on Django and connecting to a remote SQL Server database.

I conected to the remote db with this parameters:
the db is in sql server 2019, and uses Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': '*******',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '*******',
        'PORT': '15016',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            
        }, 


Then i ran

python manage.py inspectdb --database=default --include-views > vistas_generados.py


In vistas_generados.py I found several characters like this: "±" replacing the letter Ñ in the original database.

class VwWebAlumnos(models.Model):
    compa±ero1 = models.CharField(db_column='COMPAÐERO1', max_length=50, 
    blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'VW_WEB_ALUMNOS'  


i replace the "±" for any letter and the error goes away, but, of course the whole file is still encoded in a different collation than UTF-8. Its in UTF-16LE

i used class VwWebAlumnos in my views.py file importing it from vistas_generados.py

when i ran the server y got this error


File "C:\Users\Usuario\Pictures\Hipocampo\HPC\hpc\USERDATA\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from vistas_generados import VwWebActividades
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

I suspect that the problem is related to the database being encoding in Modern_Spanish_CI_AS and the way the Ñ character is being translated to vistas_generados.py when i ran inspectdb
So far, I've tried the following:

changing the encoding in vistas_generados.py to other collations, and that makes the whole file goes red in mistakes.

In settings.py, in database options:
'unicode_results': True
and also
'extra_params': 'ClientCharset=utf8'

Modifying in base.py:
mssql: unicode_results = options.get('unicode_results', True)

Some less elegant solutions like opening the generated file with Notepad and saving it in UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1



Please provide some minimal code and data that reproduces your problem. U+00B1 N'±' is rendered as 0xC2 0xB1 in UTF-8 encoding and 0xB1 in iso-8859-1, and U+00D1 N'Ñ' as 0xC3 0x91 in UTF-8 encoding and 0xD1 in iso-8859-1. On the SQL Server side when using Modern_Spanish_CI_AS N'±' is stored using 0xB1 and N'Ñ' as 0xD1. So at first blush there doesn't seem to be any way those characters could be switched around due to invalid encodings.

Is it possible that your database's default collation is something entirely different? The database's default collation affects how character literals and character scalars are interpreted and encoded. What's the output from SELECT database_id, [name], collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id=DB_ID(); when executed in that database?

okay y tried to be more clear an specific, i did not use a translator so i hope my english is good enough! thanks guys for your help. So far i read a lot and can´t find the solultion.

SQL Server identifier names (stored using SYSNAME datatype) are stored as Unicode (UTF-16) regardless of DB collation used (source). I suspect your problem is somewhere at the interface of SQL Server and Python. Keep playing with connection string / query options until you get it right.
